# Unable to deploy react app on local system. Serve is not recognized

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I am trying to deploy my react app on my system as it serves as a server to all the locally connected systems. I have made build using `npm run build`. I installed 'serve' after this using `npm install -g serve`, which is successfully installed. However while running command `serve -s build`. It shows `'serve' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` How to work this out?

Comment: When you run commands like 'which serve' do you get anything? Have you tried installing again? Which version is this? What environment are you building this in?

Comment: @rrd Uninstalled. Installed. Uninstalled. Installed. Still, same error. I followed reactJS documentation. After installing 'serve', which successfully happens, it added 78 packages. However, 'serve' is not recognized.

Answer (score 1):

Try to restart your terminal after `npm install -g serve`.
Sometimes the PATH isn't updated immediately, which can cause the error message you posted.

If that doesn't solve your issue, you'll have to add the location of the binaries to the PATH manually.